# Getting unexpect end of file with control-m characters

Tags: carriage-return

I have a simple script which give me an unexpected end of file. Everything seems good to me

```
#!/bin/bash
me="$(basename "$(test -L "$0" && readlink "$0" || echo "$0")")"
if [ $# -ge 5 ]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "$me <arg1> <arg2> <arg3> <arg4> <arg5>"
fi
```

[image]

Comment: Ah okay, because I use this line for many script and I didn't have error

Comment: I don't get this error message. Did you check, whether the line endings are correct, and in particular that the last line has the proper ending?

Comment: I added a pic of what is happening

Comment: @executable, Not at all tested, could you please try `me=$(basename "$(test -L "$0" && readlink "$0" || echo "$0")")` once and let me know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 well I got the same error https://i.imgur.com/4qPYFeP.png

Comment: @executable, also just a try, could you please also check if your file have any garbage characters in it by doing `cat -v Input_file1` and let me know if you see any control M characters in your script?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Here is the result of the command https://i.imgur.com/x2IWgeC.png

Comment: @executable, yaaay, you have got control M characters in your file use `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file  Input_file` put your script's actual name in place of `Input_file` and try this command and you should be good then.

Comment: Wow thank you a lot, I would never find it !

Comment: @executable, your welcome, not sure I should post this as an answer or not though.

Comment: Yeah you can, it answered the question very well, just need to rewrite my question

Comment: @executable : As you can see from your screenshot, the final newline is missing.

Comment: @user1934428 which one ?

Comment: ??? The FINAL one. Final == The one in the last line. Because of this, the terminating `fi` is not recognized. Just add it and run it again. Of course you should ALSO check, whether the other newlines are correct, as I told you earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking with OP in comments got to know that OP may have got control M characters in your file use `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` put your script's actual name in place of Input_file and try this command and you should be good then.

Comment: If there were carriage returns in the original script, shouldn't they be displayed as ^M when the OP did a `cat` of the file?